# unusual transitionend script behavior

Tags: javascript

hey guys have a look at the script below ::

```
  function transitionEnd() {
    var el = document.createElement('bootstrap')

    var transEndEventNames = {
      WebkitTransition : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      MozTransition    : 'transitionend',
      OTransition      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
      transition       : 'transitionend'
    }

    for (var name in transEndEventNames) {
        console.log(name);
      if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
        return { end: transEndEventNames[name] }
      }
    }
    return false // explicit for ie8 (  ._.)
  }

transitionEnd();
```

now when this script is run the following is printed to the console :

```
"WebkitTransition" 
"MozTransition"
```

now if i remove the `if` check inside the `for` loop and run the following script instead ::

```
  function transitionEnd() {
    var el = document.createElement('bootstrap')

    var transEndEventNames = {
      WebkitTransition : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      MozTransition    : 'transitionend',
      OTransition      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
      transition       : 'transitionend'
    }

    for (var name in transEndEventNames) {
        console.log(name);
    }
    return false // explicit for ie8 (  ._.)
  }


transitionEnd();
```

what prints out is the following ::

```
"WebkitTransition" 
"MozTransition" 
"OTransition" 
"transition"
```

why , i am expecting the above result to be printed in both scripts , then why am i getting differennt results ?? , also the  `console.log(name);` is before the `if` condition , so why is the `if` condition affecting the result ?

Thank you.

Alex-z .

Comment: You're first set of code worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not the if-statement, it’s the return-statement that cancels your loop (and function).

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log('Hello');
  return;

  // Unreachable code; this will never run
  console.log('World');
}
```

Return statements in loops do the exact same thing.

```
function myFunction() {
  for(var i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    return i;
  }

  // Unreachable code
  console.log('Hello World');
}
```